# bdutil socksproxy doesn't work

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, hortonworks-data-platform

I created an hadoop cluster on Google Compute engine (E.g., like [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/blob/master/platforms/hdp/README.md)). I can ssh in with `bdutil shell` without any problems, but when I run `bdutil socksproxy`, it says it is running, but whenever I connect with a browser, it says that the proxy is refusing connections. I have installed necessary browser add-ons and this has worked for me without problems last year.

How do I debug this? There are no error messages of any kind in the `bdutil socksproxy` terminal window.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

OK. Figured it out. I'm going to answer my own question in case it helps anyone else. You may have to use `ssh-keygen` or the proxy rejects request. (Running the `gcloud compute ssh` command manually will print out a message with the proper `ssh-keygen` command to use).